# Extract certain values from string in .txt files with PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, extract

Im trying to extract certain values from multiple lines inside a .txt file with PowerShell. Im currently using multiple replace and remove cmd's but it doesn't work as expected and is a bit too complex. 
Is there a more simple way to do this?

My script:

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\RS232_COM2*"

foreach($line in $file){
$result1 = $file.replace(" <<<  [NAK]#99","")
$result2 = $result1.remove(0,3) #this only works for the first line for some reason...
$result3 = $result2.replace("\(([^\)]+)\)", "") #this should remove the string within paranthesis but doesn't work
```

.txt file:

```
29 09:10:16.874 (0133563471) <<<  [NAK]#99[CAR]0998006798[CAR]
29 09:10:57.048 (0133603644) <<<  [NAK]#99[CAR]0998019022[CAR]
29 09:59:56.276 (0136542798) <<<  [NAK]#99[CAR]0998016987[CAR]
29 10:05:36.728 (0136883233) <<<  [NAK]#99[CAR]0998050310[CAR]
29 10:55:36.792 (0139883179) <<<  [NAK]#99[CAR]099805241D[CAR]0998028452[CAR]
29 11:32:16.737 (0142083132) <<<  [NAK]#99[CAR]0998050289[CAR]0998031483[CAR]
29 11:34:16.170 (0142202566) <<<  [NAK]#99[CAR]0998034787[CAR]
29 12:01:56.317 (0143862644) <<<  [NAK]#99[CAR]0998005147[CAR]
```

The output i expect:

```
09:10:16.874 [CAR]0998006798[CAR]
09:10:57.048 [CAR]0998019022[CAR]
09:59:56.276 [CAR]0998016987[CAR]
10:05:36.728 [CAR]0998050310[CAR]
10:55:36.792 [CAR]099805241D[CAR]0998028452[CAR]
11:32:16.737 [CAR]0998050289[CAR]0998031483[CAR]
11:34:16.170 [CAR]0998034787[CAR]
12:01:56.317 [CAR]0998005147[CAR]
```

Comment: `$result1 = $file.replace` -> `$result1 = $line.replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or more simple:

```
$Array = @()
foreach ($line in $file)
{
$Array += $line -replace '^..\s' -replace '\s\(.*\)' -replace '<<<.*#\d+'
}
$Array
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues.

Inside the loop you reference `$file` rather than `$line`. In the last operation, you're using the `String.Replace()` method with a regex pattern - something that method doesn't understand - use the `-replace` operator instead:

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\RS232_COM2*"

foreach($line in $file){
    $line = $line.Replace(" <<<  [NAK]#99","")
    $line = $line.Remove(0,3)

    # now use the -replace operator and output the result
    $line -replace  "\(([^\)]+)\)","" 
}
```

You could do it all in one regular expression replacement:

```
$line -replace '\(\d{10}\)\ <<<\s+\[NAK]\#99',''
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Easy to understand and good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just grab the parts of a line you need with one regex and concat them:

```
$input_path = 'c:\data\in.txt'
$output_file = 'c:\data\out.txt'
$regex = '(\d+(?::\d+)+\.\d+).*?\[NAK]#99(.*)'
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { [string]::Format("{0} {1}", $_.Groups[1].Value, $_.Groups[2].Value) } > $output_file
```

The regex is

```
(\d+(?::\d+)+\.\d+).*?\[NAK]#99(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T7hn8y/1)

**Details**:

- `(\d+(?::\d+)+\.\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits followed with 1+ sequences of `:` and one or more digits, then `.` and again 1+ digits
- `.*?\[NAK]#99` - any 0+ chars other than newline as few as possible up to the first `[NAK]#99` literal char sequence
- `(.*)` - Group 2: the rest of the line

After we get all matches, the `$_.Groups[1].Value` concatenated with `$_.Groups[2].Value` yield the expected output.